# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:Communications link failure

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

My program that connects to a MySQL database was working fine. Then, without changing any code used to set up the connection, I get this exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

What happened?

The code used to get the connection:

```
private static Connection getDBConnection() throws SQLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
    String username = "user";
    String password = "pass";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://www.domain.com:3306/dbName?connectTimeout=3000";

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    return conn;
}
```

Answer (score 38):

This is a wrapped exception and not really interesting. It is the **root cause** of the exception which actually tells us something about the root cause. Please look a bit further in the stacktrace. The chance is big that you'll then face a `SQLException: Connection refused` or `SQLException: Connection timed out`.

If this is true in your case as well, then all the possible causes are:

1. IP address or hostname in JDBC URL is wrong.
2. Hostname in JDBC URL is not recognized by local DNS server.
3. Port number is missing or wrong in JDBC URL.
4. DB server is down.
5. DB server doesn't accept TCP/IP connections.
6. Something in between Java and DB is blocking connections, e.g. a firewall or proxy.

To solve the one or the either, follow the following advices:

1. Verify and test them with `ping`.
2. Refresh DNS or use IP address in JDBC URL instead.
3. Verify it based on `my.cnf` of MySQL DB.
4. Start it.
5. Verify if mysqld is started without the `--skip-networking` option.
6. Disable firewall and/or configure firewall/proxy to allow/forward the port.

By the way (and unrelated to the actual problem), you don't necessarily need to load the JDBC driver on *every* `getConnection()` call. Just only once during startup is enough.

Comment: Thanks for your tips.Finally found that it is the shadowsocks proxy make my java client can not reach the mysql cluster sql node.

Answer (score 12):

check your wait timeout set on the DB server.
Some times it defaults to 10 seconds. This looses the connection in 10 seconds.

```
mysql> show global variables like '%time%' ;
```

update it make it something like 28800

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL wait_timeout = 28800;
```

Comment: I also found wait_timeout being defaulted to 10 seconds in MySQL docker image v5.6.36. According to MySQL documentation, this defines the number of seconds the server waits for activity on a non-interactive connection before closing it. Changed it to the recommended default value 28800 and the problem got solved.

Comment: How to do that in cpanel. Please let me know

Answer (score 5):

I've been having this issue also for about 8-9 days.
Here's some background: I'm developing a simple Java application that runs in bash.

Details:

- Spring 2.5.6
- Hibernate3.2.3.ga
- With maven.
  (The base of the project is from mkyong.com , the spring tutorial without anotations )
- MySQL version:

```
[jvazquez@archbox ~]$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.9, for Linux (i686) using readline 5.1
Linux archbox 2.6.37-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Feb 18 16:58:42 UTC 2011 i686 Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU Q8200 @ 2.33GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
```

The application works fine in Arch Linux, Mac OS X 10.6, and FreeBSD 7.2.
When I moved the jar file to another arch linux in a different host, using the same mysql, a similar my.cnf, and the similar kernel version, the connection died and obtained the same error as the original poster:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure

I tried every possible combination for this that I found on so and the forums (http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,180347,180347#msg-180347 for example, which is closed now and I can't post .. ), specifically:

- Triple check that I wasn't using skip
  networking. (verified with ps aux
  and the my.cnf)
- Tried enable log_warnings=1 in the my.cnf but obviously, I wasn't hitting the
  server so I didn't saw anything while using the app
- SHOW ENGINE innodb STATUS didn't show anything at all; during the tests I could connect via shell, and php also connected to the mysql server
- /etc/hosts has localhost 127.0.0.1
- Tried the jdbc properties using localhost and 127.0.0.1 with no results
- Tried adding c3p0 and changed the max_wait
- Max connections in the my.cnf was changed to 900 , 2000 and still nothing *my.cnf*
- Added wait_timeout = 60 *my.cnf*
- Added net_wait_timeout = 360 *my.cnf*
- Added the destroy-method="close" *spring.xml*

As it was pointed out (if you look up for the same exception , you will find several so threads about the issue [Reproduce com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException with a setup of Spring, hibernate and C3P0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511855/reproduce-com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-with-a-setup-of)
 for example ).

1. If you are using tomcat, please check the security exception (again, it is on SO, you will find it )
2. Check that you can resolve that url that you are using
3. Try adding c3p0.
4. Verify that there isn't a firewall rejecting your connections
5. Finally , if you are using GNU/Linux  ( ARch linux for example and you indeed obtain this exception )
   Try
   [MySQL Forums :: JDBC and Java :: EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,277481,286736#msg-286736)

If the link get's removed, just add mysqld:ALL to /etc/hosts.allow

**I know that is a bit extense**, but it may help anybody using GNU/Linux and having this exception and this thread seemed the best place to post my research.

Hope it helps

Comment: I have a similar setup in the fact that I am using Spring and having the same issue.

Comment: So did either of you find a solution? Having a similar problem as well.

Comment: Yep steve, my solution was
adding mysqld:ALL to /etc/hosts.allow
It's been a while and that box was lost, but that was the solution I used back then.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error
but then I figured it out its because the **Mysql server is not running** at that time.

So to change the status of the server

1. Go to Task Manager
2. Go to Services
3. then search for your Mysql server(eg:for my case its MYSQL56)
4. then you will see under the status column it says its not running
5. by right clicking and select start

Hope this will help.

Comment: @Lucky Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 3):

We have a piece of software (webapp with Tomcat) using Apache commons connection pooling, and worked great for years. In the last month I had to update the libraries due to an old bug we were encountering. The bug had been fixed in a recent version.

Shortly after deploying this, we started getting exactly these messages. Out of the thousands of connections we'd get a day, a handful (under 10, usually) would get this error message. There was no real pattern, except they would sometimes cluster in little groups of 2 to 5.

I changed the options to on the pool to validate the connection every time one is taken from or put back in the pool (if one is found bad, a new one is generated instead) and the problem went away.

Have you updated your MySQL jar lately? It seems like there may be a new setting that didn't used to be there in our (admittedly very old) jar.

I agree with BalusC to try some other options on your config, such as those you're passing to MySQL (in addition to the connection timeout).

If this failure is transient like mine was, instead of permanent, then you could use a simple try/catch and a loop to keep trying until things succeed or use a connection pool to handle that detail for you.

Other random idea: I don't know what happens why you try to use a closed connection (which exception you get). Could you be accidentally closing the connection somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

Ensure skip-networking is commented out in my.cnf/my.ini

Answer (score 2):

As BalusC mentioned, it would be very useful to post the **full** stacktrace (always post a full stacktrace, it is useless and frustrating to have only the first lines of a stacktrace).

Anyway, you mentioned that your code **was working** fine and that this problem started suddenly to occur without any code change so I'm wondering if this could be related to you other question [Problem with not closing db connection while debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121805/problem-with-not-closing-db-connection-while-debugging) Actually, if this problem started while debugging, then I think it is (you ran out of connections). In that case, restart you database server (and follow the suggestions of the other question to avoid this situation).

Answer (score 1):

I encountered same problem. I am using spring & dbcp & mysql 5.5But If I change `localhost` to `192.168.1.110` then everything works. What make things more weird is `mysql -h localhost` just works fine.

update: Finally found a solution. Changing bindaddress to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` in `my.conf` will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the local loopback interface wasn't started, so "localhost" couldn't be resolved.
You can check this by running "ifconfig" and you should see an interface called "lo". If it is not up, you can activate it by running "ifup lo" or "ifconfig lo up".

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the **mysql.com downloaded Connector/J 5.1.29 .jar had this error** whereas the **5.1.29 .jar downloaded from the MvnRepository did not**.

This happened when building a Google appengine application in Android Studio (gradle, Windows x64), communicating to a Linux MySQL server on the local network/local VM.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are connecting to a remote host. Now the question is what type of a network are you using to connect to the internet?

**WINDOWS**

If it's a *mobile broadband device* then get your machines IP address and add it to your hosting server so that your host server can allow connections coming from your machine.[your host might have turned this off due to security reasons].
Note that every time you use a different network device your IP changes.

If you are using a LAN then set a static IP address on your machine then add it to your host.

I hope this helps!!  **:)**

Answer (score 0):

I got the communications failure error when using a java.sql.PreparedStatement with a specific statement.

This was running against MySQL 5.6, Tomcat 7.0.29 and JDK 1.7.0_67 on a Windows 7 x64 machine.

The cause turned out to be setting an integer to a string parameter and a string to an integer parameter then trying to perform executeQuery on the prepared statement.  After I corrected the order of parameter setting the statement performed correctly.

This had nothing to do with network issues as the wording of the error message suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The escential problem is that Mysql JDBC pool connections is not used, then the Timeout from Mysql, close the Connections.  You need change the pool Parameters to get restart connection when the connection has failures, on this way:

`Connection Validation`:       Required    (Check)
`Validation Method:`           autocommit

You can change the Validation Method if you cannot get it works!

Answer (score 0):

If you use WAMP, make sure it is online. What I did was, first turned my firewall off, then it worked, so after that I allowed connection for all local ports, specially port 80. Than I got rid of this problem. For me it was the Firewall who was blocking the connection.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I used most of the params (autoreconnect etc..), but didn't try the (test_on_idle, or test_on_connect) , I am going to do them next.

However, I had this hack that got me through this:

I have a cron job called Healthcheck, It wakes up every 10 mins and makes a REST API call to the server. The web / app server picks this up, connects to the db, makes a small change and comes back with a 'yes all quiet on western front' or 'shitshappening'. When the latter, it sends a pager / email to the right people.

It has the side effect of always keeping the db connection pool fresh.  So long as this cron is running, I don't have the db connection timeout issues. otherwise, they crop up.