# connecting to remote mysql server throwing errors

Tags: java, mysql, bluej

I am trying to connect to a remote server (my schools server to access the database) but I am not having any luck i keep getting this

```
SQL Exception:
State  : 08S01
Message: Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
Error  : 0
```

Here is a code i found in Java, just copied to see if i can connect..

```
public void test()
 {
    try
    {
       // Load the database driver
       Class.forName( "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" ) ;

       // Get a connection to the database
       Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mysql://my.db.url.edu;databaseName=marco;user=USERNAME;password=PASSWORD" ) ;

       // Print all warnings
       for( SQLWarning warn = conn.getWarnings(); warn != null; warn = warn.getNextWarning() )
       {
          System.out.println( "SQL Warning:" ) ;
          System.out.println( "State  : " + warn.getSQLState()  ) ;
          System.out.println( "Message: " + warn.getMessage()   ) ;
          System.out.println( "Error  : " + warn.getErrorCode() ) ;
       }

       // Get a statement from the connection
       Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;

       // Execute the query
       ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM Test" ) ;

       // Loop through the result set
       while( rs.next() )
          System.out.println( rs.getString(1) ) ;

       // Close the result set, statement and the connection
       rs.close() ;
       stmt.close() ;
       conn.close() ;
   }
   catch( SQLException se )
   {
       System.out.println( "SQL Exception:" ) ;

       // Loop through the SQL Exceptions
       while( se != null )
       {
          System.out.println( "State  : " + se.getSQLState()  ) ;
          System.out.println( "Message: " + se.getMessage()   ) ;
          System.out.println( "Error  : " + se.getErrorCode() ) ;

          se = se.getNextException() ;
       }
   }
   catch( Exception e )
   {
      System.out.println( e ) ;
   }
 }
}
```

Just to complement the information, I am using Vista. What can be the issue?

Regards

Comment: the server might be configured not to accept remote connection

Comment: Hopefully this is your school not allowing everything on the internet to get to the database.

Comment: its not i changed that part :) - oh, no actually we need to connect to that database.. but no luck..maybe it is something they need to check there

Comment: Try connecting to the database remotely with MySQL command line client. If it is not connecting then they have the networking disabled or only listening to local host

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: DB Communications Link Failure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121829/java-db-communications-link-failure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible reasons why you get 'link failure' while connecting to your databse.

1. Firewalls and/or routers blocking your connection to the db
2. The database itself doesn't allow remote connection

If you are sure that case 2 doesn't apply you would have to check things on your side, switch off your antivirus/firewall software on development machine, if that doesn't work contact the db administrator.

Comment: Great how can I allow remote connections on that database, I can login using SSH but not from the java program

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html