# Jmeter: Unable to connect to ssl enabled MySQL sever through jdbc connection configuration with useSSL=true

Tags: mysql, ssl, jdbc, jmeter

I am trying to do a ssl connection to MySQL server through jmeter.

MySQL server is ssl enabled and in jmeter JDBC Connection Configuration- Database URL is configured as:

```
jdbc:mysql://<DBIP>:3306/mysql?verifyServerCertificate=false&requireSSL=true&useSSL=true
```

the response returned is:

```
Response message: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 5 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 5 milliseconds ago.
```

Error screen is attached [ssl connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5jfG.png).
Can anyone help me to solve this issue? I am missing any configuration?

I am able to make non-ssl connection with "useSSL=false", so MySQL server is reachable and port 3306 is opened.!

Answer (score 0):

Could you show your jdbc request configuration ?
Also could yoy show jmeter.log content ?

Try testing the connection outside of jmetet with this java program:

- http://razorsql.com/articles/mysql_ssl_jdbc.html

Also read this on possible causes of exception

- [com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:Communications link failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121829/mysql-jdbc-communications-link-failure)