# Protege_OBDA_Plugin_Connection_DataBase

Tags: jdbc, protege4

I'm trying to connect the database in Protege.
I've successfully installed OBDA plug-in, but I'm facing problems in connecting to the database.
When I fill the connection parameters:

Datasource Name: newSource
connection URL: jdbc:mysql://127.26.56.130\phpmyadmin:3306
Database Username: root
Database Password: ****
Driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

I get this message "No suitable driver for jdbc:mysql://127.26.56.130\phpmyadmin:3306"

I don't know if I haven't put the driver at right place (in .../Protege_5.0/)

Best regards.

I solved this problem by addind com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.jar in Protege > Preferences > jdbc drivers.

An other error message I'm getting now is "Communication link failure the last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. (ERR-CODE : 0)"

I ve been surfing on the web for similar problems, they say that you have to modify the /etc/mysql/config 
But I'm not working on mysql locally so I don't have this config file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL-JDBC: Communications Link Failure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121829/mysql-jdbc-communications-link-failure)

Comment: I've just solved it.
In fact the problem was due to an error in my connection parameters.
The connection URL should be "jdbc:mysql://127.26.56.130:3306" instead of "jdbc:mysql://127.26.56.130\phpmyadmin:3306".

Thanks anyway.

Best.