# connecting to mySql database using jdbc and toad extension in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, jdbc, toad

I have downloaded the following version of mysql JConnector 5.1.18 and i am trying to connect mysql database for the desktop application.

but following error occurs

"Connection has failed.
Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 "

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121829/mysql-jdbc-communications-link-failure

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql