# Connectivity issue with amazon instances

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, jboss

I had the problem yesterday, two of my instances where my app and db server are running are frequently having connectivity issue for some unknowing reason and after rebooting these instance all went fine. Still struggling what might be the reason and how to avoid this in future.

Sharing you the instances from the log file. Awaiting for the suggestion.

**11.57 AM:** java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
We had to restart the jboss of application2 server to bring the application up

**2:27 PM** Communication link failure in App1 server
Application1 jboss was down. Had to restarted jboss in application1

**3:42 PM** Both application servers were showing abnormal behaviors
Reason:

```
 1. jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link
    failure between app server and db server
 2. java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
```

We had to restart both of the app server to make the application up

4:12 PM Both  app server were stopped
Reason:

```
 1. jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link  
    failure between app server and db server
 2. java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
```

After rebooting both of the instances and restarted both of the app server, the application went up and running fine.

Comment: from my view, it is no related with aws instance. you need focus  on jboss and database troubleshooting. By the way, what database do you use? separate ec2 instance or aws RDS?

Comment: Its a my sql db. separate ec2 instance.

Comment: any jboss error or db connection errors?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121829/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexceptioncommunications-link-fail

Comment: Its a java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe once again happened today and in production env. Had to restart to make the app up. Any more input you need please let me know.

Comment: Can you add <datasources> section from your jboss configuration? A validation block may improve the behavior, in case it's not there yet.