# Cannot connect to mysql server from java

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection

I get the error `"Communications link failure"` at this line of code:

```
mySqlCon = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://**server ip address**:3306/db-name", "mu-user-name", "my-password");
```

I checked everything in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql):

- I increased max-allowed-packet in my.cnf in etc/mysql: max_allowed_packet    = 5073741824------ [mysqldump] max_allowed_packet   = 1G
- The bind-address is: 127.0.0.1
- All timeout values are equal to a number
- Tomcat is not yet installed on server (new server)
- There is no skip-networking in my.cnf
- I can ping the server
- I am connected to the mysql database via ssh

When I change the query string to this:

```
mySqlCon = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://**server ip address**:22/127.0.0.1:3306/db-name", "mu-user-name", "my-password");
```

I get the error `Packet for query is too large (4739923 > 1048576). You can change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet' variable.`

While I have changed the packet size on my.cnf and restarted the mysql service after that.

Any suggestions?

NOTE:

I can connect through ssh with this code, but this way doesn't seem rational! I can connect once in main and then I should pass the connection to all the classes.

```
public my-class-constructor() {

        try {
            go();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mySqlCon = null;
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + rhost + ":" + lport + "/";
        String db = "my-db-name";
        String dbUser = "dbuser";
        String dbPasswd = "pass";
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            mySqlCon = DriverManager.getConnection(url + db, dbUser, dbPasswd);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void go() {
        String user = "ssh-user";
        String password = "ssh-pass";
        String host = "ips-address";
        int port = 22;
        try {
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
            lport = 4321;
            rhost = "localhost";
            rport = 3306;
            session.setPassword(password);
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            System.out.println("Establishing Connection...");
            session.connect();
            int assinged_port = session.setPortForwardingL(lport, rhost, rport);
            System.out.println("localhost:" + assinged_port + " -> " + rhost
                    + ":" + rport);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.print(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you able to ping the server?

Comment: it seems your query is too large, try a smaller query e.g. "select * from table limit 10;"

Comment: If the MySQL database is remote, have you configured the permissions correctly?

Comment: did you check "max-allowed-packet" against the size from the error message?

Comment: what are you trying to do when you get that error?

Comment: Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121829/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexceptioncommunications-link-fail

Comment: I am currently connected to the server through ssh, and I can work on mysql there in command prompt. i get the error exactly at the line I put in the question, I don't run any sql query yet.

Comment: I can ping the server.

Comment: max_allowed_packet = 5073741824------
[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet = 1G

Comment: Please provide the MySQL version and the jdbc veraion. I will try to reproduce the issue locally today or tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry I was trying to find my jdbc version. I am still workin gon it. MySQL 5.6, Java SE-1.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the binding address in my.cnf file in /etc/mysql to the ip address of the server, and it solved the problem.

Comment: good to hear that you've managed with this, thanks for the update

Answer (score 3):

Take a look [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/packet-too-large.html) .
Looks the following describes your case

> The largest possible packet that can be transmitted to or from a MySQL
>   5.7 server or client is 1GB.
>
> When a MySQL client or the mysqld server receives a packet bigger than
>   max_allowed_packet bytes, it issues an ER_NET_PACKET_TOO_LARGE error
>   and closes the connection. With some clients, you may also get a Lost
>   connection to MySQL server during query error if the communication
>   packet is too large.
>
> Both the client and the server have their own max_allowed_packet
>   variable, so if you want to handle big packets, you must increase this
>   variable both in the client and in the server.

So, it looks like you need to change the `max_allowed_packet` on the client as well:

```
mySqlCon = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://**server ip address**:3306/db-name?max_allowed_packet= 5073741824", "mu-user-name", "my-password");
```

Comment: Can you try with a ssh connection too?

Comment: `mySqlCon = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://**server ip address**:22/127.0.0.1:3306/db-name?max_allowed_packet=5073741824", "mu-user-name", "my-password");`

Comment: Oh. I tried both. the same errors as before. I also tried to change the value of max_allowed_packet to another value less than this value, and tried with both. still the same errors.