# Fresh install of Tomcat 8.5.4

Tags: java, tomcat

I've freshly installed tomcat 8 as I need it to run as a windows service (automatically start on startup)

I've set the *CATALINA_HOME* and *java PATHS* correctly

I have set

```
 <role rolename="manager"/>
 <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
 <role rolename="admin"/>
 <user username="user" password="password" roles="admin,manager,manager-gui"/>
```

yet, the problem is,

> when I try to access the manager app through chrome, it goes straight
>   to "**403 Access Denied**" there is no prompt for a username or password

.

I've deleted old passwords related to other versions of tomcat.
I have another version of tomcat installed for development which works fine.

previous to this, the other version 8.0.33 I had installed worked fine, I just need it to run automatically upon computer startup.

thanks in advance

Comment: Please post your entire `tomcat-users.xml` file. Also, have you changed anything about your `manager` application's deployment from the default?

Comment: This might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121829/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexceptioncommunications-link-fail/33162543#33162543